# Visual Studio - Exception in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, exception

I am getting the following exception all of a sudden(it worked fine in the beginning) in the output window when using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package of Visual Studio.

Exception thrown:

```
'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll.
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Is that all you get? Please show full error message and piece of code where it happens

Comment: That's all I get. There is no line indicated. It just prints this out in the output window.

Comment: Then you may read documentation of Visual Studio, chapter: How to debug a program?

Comment: That is just the name of the exception, you need to get the details to determine what the real problem is.  See the Catch clause in the code example here:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleExceptionClass.htm#ODPNT1672

Comment: I have used the catch clause as mentioned, still no additional information has been provided inspite of even trying to print the stacktrace.